# Plesk 9.01/Centos - how do I create a directory I can upload to via PHP?

Tags: php, linux, plesk, uploading

How do I create a directory I can upload to via PHP in Plesk, considering all my PHP.INI file is correctly setup to allow uploads?

Step by step instructions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was done by reconfiguring the php.ini file, and setting folder permissions.